# How can I automatically copy screenshots to .jpg instead of .png on Windows?

Tags: windows, screenshot, jpeg, png, greenshot

I have tried various tools such as Greenshot, Ksnip, and ShareX as well as Windows clipping tool, etc., but I can only get it to save as .jpg, not copy to clipboard.

I want this because for web use I can get a compressed .jpg at 200kb that would be 10x that size with .png.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong direction. It isn't the screenshot capture that is or isn't JPG, it's the fact that the Windows Clipboard always encodes pictures in it as PNG. If you open a JPG in a photo viewer copy it to clipboard (not the file in explorer, but the actual image from the viewer) it will also then paste as PNG.

Answer (score 2):

While any image is in the clipboard, it's not in JPEG format
or any other disk-oriented format. It will be in a
memory-resident format which is bitmap or PNG.

To get for example Greenshot to save the image on the disk
as JPEG:

- Right-click the Greenshot traybar icon and select "Preferences..."
- In the "Output" tab set your folder and and name
- Set the "Image format" drop-down box to "jpg"
- Set the "JPEG quality" (mine is 100%)
- In the "Destination" tab ensure that "Save directly"
  is checked ("Copy to clipboard" is optional and not required).
  You can optionally add a check-mark next to an image-editor
  that will open automatically the saved image
- Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can do this already, but it wastes a lot of time. Is there any such software that can automatically save .jpg in clipboard? Just like when I use greenshot to create the .jpg, and then copy that image, that .jpg is now in the clipboard and I can paste it other places like the browser or the file manager I use.

Comment: @Eternal482223 isn't "Save directly" as harrymc suggested explicitly what you are asking for?

Comment: @Eternal482223: "Save directly" is almost immediate.

Comment: When I save directly, I have to open that folder and copy it from the folder, which takes at least 2x as long as just having it copied to the clipboard. Since apps like Greenshot will upload to places like Imgur and put the link in your clipboard, I would have assumed some app can put a compressed .jpg in your clipboard.

Comment: The point is that an image in the clipboard cannot be in JPEG format, or it won't be an image. JPEG format in the clipboard, if it existed, will be just a sequence of bytes that wouldn't be understood as an image. All of the screenshot products create images, not byte sequences. Greenshot is a very versatile tool, but it only creates screenshot images, as do all other such tools.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was confused because I could copy a .jpg and post it elsewhere like in my file explorer as a .jpg, but that was probably just copying the file. 

So I guess what I am looking for is if there is a way to auto-compress before copying to the clipboard?

Comment: In greenshot, expert, check: I know what I do, there you can set the clipboard format to something else than PNG

Comment: I just tried the clipboard format, and only the bmp and png would work when trying to paste other places, and they both created the same size png file.

Comment: @Eternal482223: The clipboard format is hardwired to be what it is (and I don't believe that it's compressed although the format might support this). The compression is done when converting the memory image to the disk image in JPEG format, so it's done *after*, not *before*. There is really no way to avoid it, the screenshot is just a snapshot of the pixels from the screen buffer area that is kept by Windows, so it's not in a sophisticated image format like JPEG, and was never meant to be.

Comment: You may perhaps be able to automate uploading the JPEG file from disk into the clipboard, but that's another story.

Answer (score -1):

A screenshot is going to be in some uncompressed format such as PNG TIF OR BMP as screens are not compressed. However, once you take a screenshot, there are plenty of tools that can then permanently save it as a jpg.

Windows `Snipping Tool` for instance can save the screenshot by selecting `FILE > SAVE AS...` and selecting `JPG`.

Comment: png, tif and bmp all support compression.

Comment: @Yorik, I didn't say that didn't support compression. I said as screenshots they are uncompressed formats as screens are not compressible.

Comment: @Brian - The format of a screenshot isn’t determined until the file extension is chosen. The absolutely disagree with the technical statement contained within this answer.